# How to configure in VsCode to connect to DolphinDB server using DolphinDB C# API?

Tags: c#, database, api, visual-studio-code, dolphindb

I've created a c# project successfully in VsCode using commands below:

```
$ dotnet new console -o /home/hj/c#Test
$ cd /c#Test
$ dotnet run
```

And I want to connect to DolphinDB server in my c# project. So how to configure DolphinDB C# API files so that I can execute the codes below?

```cs
using dolphindb;
using dolphindb.data;
using dolphindb.io;

public void Test_Connect()
{
    DBConnection conn=new DBConnection();
    Assert.AreEqual(true,conn.connect("localhost",1220));
}
```

Here is the [tutorial](https://github.com/dolphindb/api-csharp) I've followed.

Answer (score 0):

C# code can be compiled with command line tool "csc.exe"

you can find the usage of csc.exe here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/index

`- Reference` parameter is used to add a reference to dolphindb-charpapi.dll